# Scala: A extends Ordered[A]

Tags: scala, sorting, generics

I've just started learning Scala and I decided, for practice, to create a Pair[A, B] class that when sorted will first be sorted by As and then by Bs. My first attempt was this:

```
case class Pair[A <: Ordered[A], B <: Ordered[B]](val left: A, val right: B) extends Ordered[Pair[A, B]]
{
  override def compare(that: Pair[A, B]) = {
      val leftCompare = this.left.compare(that.left)
      if (leftCompare == 0)
        this.right.compare(that.right)
      else
        leftCompare
    }
}

object Main extends App
{
  List(Pair(1, "a"), Pair(5, "b"), Pair(5, "a"), Pair(1, "b")).sorted
}
```

This is the way I want it to be done, really. I want to extend Ordered and have it work from that, so I can just do things like List(whatever).sortWith(_ < _) or List(whatever).sorted, like I've written in Main. I get the following errors:

```
pair.scala:14: error: inferred type arguments [Int,String] do not conform to method apply's type parameter bounds [A <: Ordered[A],B <: Ordered[B]]
  List(Pair(1, "a"), Pair(5, "b"), Pair(5, "a"), Pair(1, "b")).sorted
```

and this for every pair in the list:

```
pair.scala:14: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int(1)
 required: A
  List(Pair(1, "a"), Pair(5, "b"), Pair(5, "a"), Pair(1, "b")).sorted
```

and this as well, which I have no understanding of:

```
pair.scala:14: error: diverging implicit expansion for type scala.math.Ordering[Pair[_ >: A with A with A with A <: scala.math.Ordered[_ >: A with A with A with A <: scala.math.Ordered[_ >: A with A with A with A]], _ >: B with B with B with B <: scala.math.Ordered[_ >: B with B with B with B <: scala.math.Ordered[_ >: B with B with B with B]]]]
starting with method $conforms in object Predef
  List(Pair(1, "a"), Pair(5, "b"), Pair(5, "a"), Pair(1, "b")).sorted
```

I managed to get it to sort, but only by writing sorting functions that were aware of the types they were sorting, rather than just being aware they were sorting types that are sortable. Here's what these "aware of the types" versions are, as I've mentioned them:

```
case class Pair[A, B](val left: A, val right: B)
{}

object Main extends App
{
  val pairs = Array(Pair(1, "a"), Pair(5, "b"), Pair(5, "a"), Pair(1, "b"))
  Sorting.quickSort(pairs)(Ordering[(Int, String)].on(x => (x.left, x.right)))
  println(pairs.toList)
}
```

and

```
case class Pair[A, B](val left: A, val right: B)
{}

object Main extends App
{
  val intStringSort = (x: Pair[Int, String], y: Pair[Int, String]) => {
    val intCompare = x.left - y.left
    if (intCompare == 0)
      x.right.compare(y.right) < 0
    else
      intCompare < 0
  }
  println(List(Pair(1, "a"), Pair(5, "b"), Pair(5, "a"), Pair(1, "b")).sortWith(intStringSort))
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Both answers taught me some new Scala things I didn't know before, so thank you to both :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `<%` instead of `<:`

```
case class Pair[A <% Ordered[A], B <% Ordered[B]]
```

because neither `Int` nor `String` are `Ordered`.

**UPDATE:**

But there are implicit conversions from `Int` to `RichInt` which is `Ordered[Int]` and from `String` to `StringOps` which is `Ordered[String]`.

`<%` means that object can be implicitly converted to defined type.
For example, `A <% Ordered[A]` for `Int` means that there is an implicit conversion from `Int` to `Ordered[Int]` which is:

```
implicit def intWrapper(x: Int)         = new runtime.RichInt(x)
```

in `scala.Predef` which is imported automatically. `RichInt` is `Ordered[Int]`. Similar steps are performed for `String`.

Comment: Could you explain why `<%` should be used instead of `<:`?

Comment: In my code, this generated a deprecated warning: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7629

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with your type bounds, `A <: Ordered[A]` and `B <: Ordered[B]`.

`Int` and `String` don't extend `Ordered`. But they do have implicit `Ordering`s available in scope, so you could use implicit bounds instead of type bounds.

```
case class Pair[A, B](left: A, right: B)(implicit a: Ordering[A], b: Ordering[B]) extends Ordered[Pair[A, B]] {

    def compare(that: Pair[A, B]) = {
        val leftCompare = a.compare(this.left, that.left)
        if (leftCompare == 0)
            b.compare(this.right, that.right)
        else
            leftCompare
    }

}

scala> List(Pair(1, "a"), Pair(3, "d"), Pair(2, "c"), Pair(2, "b")).sorted
res8: List[Pair[Int,String]] = List(Pair(1,a), Pair(2,b), Pair(2,c), Pair(3,d))
```

Note that I dropped the `val` in the case class definition, because case class fields are automatically public. `compare` also doesn't need `override` as it needs to be implemented (though it can be a style preference for some).